# declare dynamic lists in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there any provision to dynamically declare lists in Ansible playbooks ?
I want something like with set_fact or register

```
- setfact: list_name= list_of(1, {{ n }}) # should return a list of 1 to n numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

The above can be achieved as follows :

```
- name: "Registering list varibles count "
  shell: python -c "print [x for x in range( 1, {{ server_var['count'] }} )]"
  register: list_name
- name: "debug statement to checkout the output"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ list_name.stdout }}"
# the list_name.stdout can also be used as jinja list variable
```